# How to ignore comma inside the Content..?

Tags: java

```
//String[] value="name1","name2",**"name3, admin"**,"name4",**"name5,developer"**;

String[] masterData = value[0].split(",", -1);
```

my output came like this :

```
name1
name2
name3
admin
name4
name5
developer
```

but i need this output :

```
name1
name2
name3 admin
name4
name5 developer
```

This is my code :

```
String[] mContactContactsMasterData;

for (int i = 0; i < contactPhoneValue.length; i++) {    
    mContactContactsMasterData = contactPhoneValue[i].split(",", -1);
}
```

how to ignore comma inside the string value ..

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: have you used regex?. Where is your code? . Also, this isn't a String, its a String[]

Comment: `String value="name1","name2","name3, admin","name4","name5,developer";` is a valid java instruction

Comment: You don't need split...

Comment: Could it be a matter of **when** you use split? Show us the code where it happens.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: file read from csv.. that what i'm using split command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to escape the `"`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value = "\"name1\",\"name2\",\"name3, admin\",\"name4\",\"name5,developer\"";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(value.split(",(?=\")"))); \\ positive look-ahead

}
```

O/P : (matches your expected output i.e, length = 5)

```
["name1", "name2", "name3, admin", "name4", "name5,developer"]
                   <-, ignored ->
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. my original data from csv, after reading csv file some of content have inside comma(,). so that i'm trying to ignore comma..  name3 admin is single name ("name3,admin")... and name5 developer also single name ("name5 developer).. i have to ignore inside comma.

Comment: @Karthick - Doesn't my solution help?.

Comment: yes i got my expected output ... but how to use without backslash

Comment: @Karthick - You have to escape the backslash in java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean

```
String [] values = {"name1","name2","name3, admin","name4","name5,developer"};
```

Because I don't know what all the asterisks are for.   In which case you could just iterate and print

```
for (String value : values)
{
  System.out.println(value);
}
```

If you want to remove the comma in the `String`s that contain them, then instead of

```
System.out.println(value);
```

do

```
System.out.println(value.replace(",", ""));
```

or if you want to keep the value rather than printing it do

```
value = value.replace(",", " ");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. but i'm not directly print the values.my original data from csv, after reading csv file some of content have inside comma(,). so that i'm trying to ignore comma..

Comment: Then do the same thing and change the `println` for an assignment...I've edited my answer to reflect this

Comment: name3 admin is single name ("name3,admin")... and name5 developer also single name ("name5 developer)..   i have to ignore inside comma.

Comment: Then your question makes no sense.  You need to post the raw data and the code you are using to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the comma with space or an empty string like this:

```
String[] value={"name1","name2","name3, admin","name4","name5,developer"};

for ( int i =0; i < value.length; i++ )
   value[i] = value[i].replace(",", "");

for ( String str : value)
    System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're trying to parse a csv line. Your "," is both the separator and a character within your cells.

Maybe try to parse the line using https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html the csv parser - then you can replace the , in each string with spaces after the splitting.